# Solution of the heat equation: convergence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I have a question about the heat equation, if we consider the non homogeneous problem:
$$ u_{t}(x,t)=u_{x,x}(x,t) + f(x,t), \hspace{0.1cm} 0\leqslant x\leqslant L,\hspace{0.1cm} 0\leqslant t\leqslant T $$
$$u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=\phi(x)$$
When is  guaranteed the convergence of the solution $u(x,t)$?

Comment: What do you mean by convergence?

Comment: We obtain the solution of the problem as a serie, when this serie converges uniformly ?

Comment: Have you written out the solution in terms of separation of variables?